# Can't get hbase MOB record after compact_mob

Tags: hbase

I have a hbase table like this:
[image]

I insert 4 records into this table,and then I change the MOB_THRESHOLD=10240,like this:
 [image]

then run compact_mob,

I have only 4 records in my table,when I  scan this table,I got this:
[image]

that means after I changed the MOB_THRESHOLD,I can't get the MOB files?????

before I change the MOB_THRESHOLD the result of scan is like the result in the first red cube, after change the value of MOB_THRESHOLD,the result of scan is like the result in the second and third red cube, it is only a reference of HDFS files

is this a bug? (hbase version 1.2.0)

Comment: insert mod files-> change mob threshold -> compact_mob=========can't get or scan mob files

Comment: To get clarity on the question. The steps done are: 1) there were 4 MOB records in the table. 2) Updated the records with new data 3) MOB_THRESHOLD was increased to 10240 4) Compaction was triggered. Now the question is either you were not able to see the old records? or you are not able to see 4 MOB records in that table?